# Why doesn't IronPython support SQLite3's Write-Ahead Logging, even though its SQLite version should?

Tags: python, sqlite, ironpython

I'm attempting to set a SQLite database's journal_mode to wal (write-ahead logging) via an IronPython script.

The IronPython's install version is

> IronPython 2.7 2.7.5.0 on .NET 4.0.30319.18444

and the SQLite version it uses is 3.7.7, obtained by running `print sqlite3.sqlite_version`.

WAL support was added to SQLite in [version 3.7.0](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), so why does this script fail to run?

If I execute `pragma journal_mode=wal;` I just get a response of `delete`.

If I try to open a database already set to WAL, I get an error of `_sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database (wal format detected)`.

Comment: If anyone else stumbles across this, you can work around this by setting WAL via the SQLite command line tool (sqlite3.exe) by running `sqlite3 dbname "pragma journal_mode=wal;"` if you have it.  This can be done from within the Python script once you close the database, but the database can't be reopened by the script afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The [PRAGMA journal_mode documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) says:

> If the journal mode could not be changed, the original journal mode is returned. […]
>   Note also that the journal_mode cannot be changed while a transaction is active.

So you have to ensure that the databsae library does not try to be clever and automatically starts a transaction.

However, this would not prevent the opening of a WAL database.
It is possible to [remove WAL support](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#omit_wal) from the SQLite library.
Apparently, this was done by your database driver for some reason; you have to use any other SQLite driver if you want to be able to use WAL.

Comment: IronPython uses the c#-sqlite library which does implement WAL support. Future versions will switch to using the native library one I figure out a sane way to do it.